# Abnormal Connection Count in DocumentDB Instances

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

I am currently managing a MongoDB cluster using DocumentDB, and I am wondering if that the connection count for all instances consistently hovers around 25 (always) even when no active users are interacting with the app/portal.

I'm using Laravel for the backend, and I am wondering if this behavior is normal or not.

Basically my Question:

- Is it normal to have a relatively high and constant connection count of 20-25 on DocumentDB instances, even during periods when the application is not in active use?
- How can I trace the origin of these connections to determine where they are coming from and why they persist, especially during periods of inactivity?

Any insights or suggestions on how to investigate and address this issue (if its an issue) would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]